# Include Angular inside a TypeScript file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have a type script file and want to include angular.

I have the following throwing errors when compiling the typescript as angular is not included as a referenced file or anything:

**app.ts**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" type="text/css" />
</body>
</html>
```

Obviously it does not matter that my index.html file correctly states dependencies in order as the compiler has no idea where angular comes from.

How do i include the external files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare angular variable to tell compiler something like angular will be presented at runtime. You can combine it together with downloading already existing declaration file from DefinitelyTyped [github](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) repository.

If you don't want to do that, you an just use this instead:

```
declare var angular:any;
```

But I highly recommend using DefinitelyTyped Angular.js declarations, and declarations for all other 3rd party libraries for that matter. You will get code completion support.

Comment: Cheers mate. Spot on!